# maas-import-pxe-files –sources-file <sources> Can't connect to the region

Tags: juju, maas, cloud

I'm installing ubuntu openstack based on that website: http://www.ubuntu.com/download/cloud/install-ubuntu-openstack

I started the second step, but after installing MAAS, it failed to download boot images. I start to import the boot images manually as following:

1- I tried

```
sudo maas maas node-groups import-boot-images
```

- it gives "Import of boot images started on all cluster controllers"
- but when I check  ps -ae | grep maas , it gives nothing.

2- So I try the following:

```
sudo maas-import-pxe-files
```

- it gives "usage: maas-import-pxe-files [-h] --source-file SOURCES_FILE
            maas-import-pxe-files: error: argument --source-file is required"
  3- I have a sources file called "/var/lib/maas/boot-resources/bootresources.yaml" with the following content:

*boot:*

*sources:*

- keyring: /usr/share/keyrings/ubuntu-cloudimage-keyring.gpg

  path: http://maas.ubuntu.com/images/ephemeral-v2/releases/

  selections:

  - arches:

    - i386
    - amd64

    labels:

    - release

    release: trusty

    subarches:

    - generic
  - arches:

    - i386
    - amd64

    labels:

    - release

    release: precise

    subarches:

    - generic

  storage: /var/lib/maas/boot-resources/

and I do

```
sudo maas-import-pxe-files --source-file /var/lib/maas/boot-resources/bootresources.yaml
```

- it gives "Can't connect to the region"

Any suggestions???

Comment: I've same problem with MaaS 1.7

Answer (score 1):

Same issue here...

I installed 2 days ago and everything was fine until I get a message today saying that there is no boot image available (but they were downloaded back then...)

I thought it was a misconfiguration so I reinstalled everything, and I get the same issue.

I guess next time I will install a local proxy... there might be an issue currently with the structure of the remote repo ?

And yes I can resolve maas.ubuntu.com

*seb@master-maas-controller:~$ ping maas.ubuntu.com
PING maas.ubuntu.com (91.189.89.122) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from citrusnobilis.canonical.com (91.189.89.122): icmp_seq=1 ttl=47 time=80.8 ms
64 bytes from citrusnobilis.canonical.com (91.189.89.122): icmp_seq=2 ttl=47 time=89.4 ms
64 bytes from citrusnobilis.canonical.com (91.189.89.122): icmp_seq=3 ttl=47 time=89.0 ms
64 bytes from citrusnobilis.canonical.com (91.189.89.122): icmp_seq=4 ttl=47 time=88.6 ms
64 bytes from citrusnobilis.canonical.com (91.189.89.122): icmp_seq=5 ttl=47 time=88.7 ms
^C
--- maas.ubuntu.com ping statistics ---
5 packets transmitted, 5 received, 0% packet loss, time 4005ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 80.818/87.356/89.434/3.290 ms*

Any idea ?